# How to use React useState and useHistory functionality in vanila JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Okay So heres the thing. I made an login and signup auth. using JWT token in backend and  fetched it using useState() and useHistory() hooks in Frontend React. And now I wannted to make same login and signup auth for another project but here I am not allowed to use React. So now How can I fetch that in frontend using Vanilla JS. And also JWT is working in this I am getting my auth-token. So is there any way I can do this using vanilla JS?

Heres How I was fetching in Frontend in my previous Project.

````
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = (props) => {
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({email: "" , password:""})
    let history = useHistory();

    const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
          //API call
    const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({email: credentials.email,password: credentials.password}),
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        
        console.log(json);
        //below if else for if credentials are true save the token in local storage and redirect the user to home
        if (json.success){
            // Save the auth token and redirect
            localStorage.setItem('token', json.authToken); 
            props.showAlert(" Logged in successfully", "success")
            history.push("/");


        }
        else{
          props.showAlert(" Invalid Credentials", "danger")

        }
        
        
    }
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };


    return (
      <div className="mt-3">
        <h2>Login to continue to iCloud Notebook</h2>
        <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div className="mb-3">
    <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" value={credentials.email}  onChange={onChange} name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
    <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
  </div>
  <div className="mb-3">
    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" className="form-control" value={credentials.password}  onChange={onChange} name="password" id="password"/>
  </div>
  
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
    )
}
export default Login```
````

Comment: State requires either a state management library or you have to make it yourself. For `useHistory`, just use the normal `window.history` API

Comment: "_So is there any way I can do this using vanilla JS?_" - define _this_ as it is used in that statement? This is a very, very broad question that isn't focused enough. Certainly you can log in using oAuth2 using vanilla JavaScript. Is your question about how to store/access the authenticated state or how to notify the app or literally how to log in using a JWT? Please narrow and clarify your question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I wanted to log in using JWT.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.